# Magento 2.2 move review tab below description with all product reviews

Tags: product, layout, magento2.2.2, product-review

I have added the following code to '*Magento_Review/layout/catalog_product_view.xml*':

```
<move element="reviews.tab" destination="content" after="product.info.details" />
```

The above code moved the review tab just below product's '**Details / More Information**' container.

But, the **Div** '**product-review-container**' is empty.

Following are descriptive images of before and after moving review tab:

***Before moving review tab :*** 
[image]

---

---

***After moving review tab:***
[image]

Please help me in rectifying this.

Comment: This works fine for me. So the moved element is empty?

Comment: @harri : I have updated my answer with clear picture to make my question more cleare.

Answer (score 5):

You will also need to add the below block in your layout I have added it under `<block class="Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\View\Description" name="product.info.details" template="product/view/details.phtml" after="product.info.media">`:

```
<block class="Magento\Review\Block\Product\Review" name="reviews.tab" as="reviews" template="Magento_Review::review.phtml" group="detailed_info">
                    <block class="Magento\Review\Block\Product\View\ListView" name="product.info.product_additional_data" as="product_additional_data" template="product/view/list.phtml"/>
                    <block class="Magento\Theme\Block\Html\Pager" name="product_review_list.toolbar"/>
                    <block class="Magento\Review\Block\Form" name="product.review.form" as="review_form">
                        <container name="product.review.form.fields.before" as="form_fields_before" label="Review Form Fields Before"/>
                    </block>
                </block>
```

Comment: Thanks, @shireen-n

Answer (score 3):

The problem is from process-reviews.js file from vendor/magento/module-review/view/frontend/web/js.
Function processReviews is not called, that's why the container remains empty. 
Copy the file in your theme and remove code from line 40 to 49 and just call processReviews function and it will work.

---

Instead of:

```
    var reviewTab = $(config.reviewsTabSelector),
        requiredReviewTabRole = 'tab';

    if (reviewTab.attr('role') === requiredReviewTabRole && reviewTab.hasClass('active')) {
        processReviews(config.productReviewUrl);
    } else {
        reviewTab.one('beforeOpen', function () {
            processReviews(config.productReviewUrl);
        });
    }
```

use:

```
    processReviews(config.productReviewUrl);
```

Answer (score 1):

it's works fine for me.
Kindly review attached screenshot for reference. 
[image]

Comment: But It is not working on my end

Comment: Can you see any js error in console?