# Show Product Review List Below Review form on product page in magento2

Tags: magento2, product-review

I want to show the Customer Reviews list below the review form
Does anyone know a solution?
[image]

Comment: https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/209256/magento-2-2-move-review-tab-below-description-with-all-product-reviews

Comment: this will work for you

Comment: ANYONE KNOW HOW TO POSSIBLE VIA catalog_product_view.xml FILE?

Answer (score 0):

You need to copy the below file in your custom theme:

> vendor/magento/module-review/view/frontend/templates/review.phtml
> and change calling the child HTML function position:

from

```
<div id="product-review-container" data-role="product-review"></div>
<?php echo $block->getChildHtml(); ?>
```

to

```
<?php echo $block->getChildHtml(); ?>
<div id="product-review-container" data-role="product-review"></div>
```

Comment: ANYONE KNOW HOW TO POSSIBLE VIA catalog_product_view.xml FILE?

Comment: No, There is no way to change position using XML because both date coming from vendor/magento/module-review/view/frontend/templates/review.phtml

Comment: this doesn't work